# Compiling asp.net core 8.0 sources

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, dotnet-sdk

I've downloaded ASP.Net Core sources from: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore .
Then build them using instructions from: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/docs/BuildFromSource.md .
Using this walkthrough (plus script \eng\build.ps1) I've successfully downloaded main and depended code (using git and /restore.cmd), prepare visual studio (./eng/scripts/InstallVisualStudio.ps1) and compile (\eng\build.ps1). I'm happy of that. But I'm encountering errors while building code in Visual Studio 2022. I think that problematic is sdk, which still is dependency of aspnetcore code. This sdk is in version 8.0.100-rc.1.23381.2, that already can't be downloaded (the link, which is suggested by blazor console server is not available: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=8.0.0-rc.1.23404.1&arch=x64&rid=win-x64&os=win10) .
I've got 8.0.0-preview.7.23375.6 sdk installed, but mayby this version cause errors (for example: ... webassembly.js does not exist. Enable nodejs to build ...). I would like to use sdk: 8.0.100-rc.1.23381.2, which is defined in ASP.Net Core solution (in \global.json). Any suggestion how can I managed to code to compile and run?

Comment: don't download from `main` - you'll have to find the tag with the right version

Comment: "But I'm encountering errors while building code in Visual Studio 2022."What's error do you get ?  Do you try to install manually the sdk is in version 8.0.100-rc.1.23381.2  ? Besides, you can use visual studio installer to check  anything yo update or modify .

Answer (score 0):

After download aspnet core from branch release/8.0-preview7 (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/release/8.0-preview7), restore (/restore.cmd),  prepare visual studio (./eng/scripts/InstallVisualStudio.ps1) and compile (\eng\build.ps1) the code samples from solution started working. I had to use compile script first (\eng\build.ps1) then i could use visual studio to compile (without using compile script (\eng\build.ps1) or using 8.0.100-rc.1.23381.2 version i had errors during compile in visual studio:  ... webassembly.js does not exist. Enable nodejs to build ..., problems with resources and dll for iis). Now I'm on good road to some experiments.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. On visul studio, I don't unable the sdk version on global.json .

I follow the instructions of "Visual Studio Code or other editor on Windows, Linux, Mac" on execute activate.ps1 to enbale the 8.0.100-rc.1.23381.2
(deactivate to restore the sdks list)

Comment: Please post this as a comment as this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to build:
just start: ..\runtime>build.cmd in a dos windows
requires VS 2022 C++ install